# How to enforce a uniqueness constraint in a SQL database based on a certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a SQL database, and I have the following table:

**Workout Routine**

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
user_id integer
   REFERENCES users (id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
active boolean DEFAULT TRUE,
UNIQUE(user_id, name)
```

Currently, the combination of `user_id`, and `name` are supposed to be unique, meaning that a user cannot have two workout routines with the same name. However, this is not quite what I want.

Instead, I would want the combination `user_id` and `name` to be unique ***only*** in cases where `active = true`. In other words, a user should be able to have multiple workouts with the same name that are inactive, but should not be allowed to have duplicates that are active.

Is there a way to enforce this in this table?

Answer (score 4):

A partial index can be used for this:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON table_name (user_id, name) WHERE active;
```

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9buK9pWk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial index to achieve this. The index will only be used for queries that include the active column, and will only be used for queries that include the active column with a value of true. This means that queries that do not include the active column will not use the index, and queries that include the active column with a value of false will not use the index.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX workout_routine_user_id_name_active
    ON workout_routine (user_id, name)
    WHERE active = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Oracle guy - but perhaps I can be of help here. Yes, you can model what you want in several ways.

One way is to create two tables, one historical, the other current. The historical would have no unique index other than the PK on the surrogate key ID, whereas the current would also have a unique index on user_id and name.

The second way, using a single table, is to add a nullable date field that represents the closed/inactive date. NULL means active, non-NULL (a date value) would mean inactive. Create a unique index (not a PK) on user_id,name,inactive_date. If SQL Server is like Oracle and allows NULL values in a unique constraint but not multiple NULL values, that will enforce that there can be only one instance of a name for a user_id that is current (having a NULL inactive_date), but allows there to be many inactive rows since they would all have different date values.

If SQL Server acts differently than Oracle then check out the "NULLS NOT DISTINCT" option.

Comment: The question is about PostgreSQL, not SQL Server

Comment: Okay, well, my comments still apply. See if PostgreSQL has the concept of allowing NULL in a unique constraint and treating it as a distinct value (thereby allowing only one of them)... it's the concept I was conveying, not the exact implementation. And even if it doesn't, you can always use a dummy (end-of-time) date to represent NULL (still active). My approach should work one way or another in any RDBMS. I've done it many times.